# vue.js computed update on prop change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
Vue.component('app-table', {
  template: '<table><thead><tr>' +
    '<th v-for="key in headers" v-on:click="sortBy(key)" v-bind:class="sortActive(key)">{{ key }}' +
    '<span class="arrow" v-bind:class="sortIcon(key)"></span>' +
    '</th></tr></thead><tbody>' +
    '<tr v-for="entry in filteredData"><td v-for="key in headers">{{ entry[key] }}' +
    '</td></tr></tbody></table>',
  props: {
    filterKey: String,
    headers: Array,
    rows: Array
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: {}
    }
  },
 watch: {
  headers: function(val) {   
   var orders = {};
   val.forEach(function (key) { orders[key] = 1 });
   this.sortKey = '';
   this.sortOrders = orders;
  }
 },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function() {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey;
      var filterKey = this.filterKey.toLowerCase();
      var sortOrder = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1;
      var rows = this.rows;
      if (filterKey) {
        rows = rows.filter(function(row) {
          return Object.keys(row)
            .some(function(key) {
              return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
            });
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        rows = rows.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey];
          b = b[sortKey];
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * sortOrder;
        });
      }
      return rows;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function(key) {
      this.sortKey = key;
      this.sortOrders[key] = -this.sortOrders[key];
    },
    sortActive: function(key) {
      return this.sortKey == key ? 'active' : '';
    },
    sortIcon: function(key) {
      return this.sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc';
    }
  },
})
var appTable = new Vue({
  el: "#apptable",
  data: {
    gridQuery: '',
    gridHeaders: '',
    gridRows: []
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function(url) {
      /*var self = this;
      $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "JSON",
       cache: false,
       success: function (res) {
        self.gridHeaders = JSON.parse(res.headers);
        self.gridRows = JSON.parse(res.rows);    
       },
       error: function (ex) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ex));
       }
      })*/
      this.gridHeaders = ['1', '2', '3'];
      this.gridRows = [{
        '1': 'a',
        '2': 'b',
        '3': 'c'
      }, {
        '1': 'm',
        '2': 'n',
        '3': 'k'
      }, {
        '1': 'g',
        '2': 'j',
        '3': 'd'
      }];
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="apptable">
  <form id="search">
    Поиск: <input name="query" v-model="gridQuery">
  </form>
  <button v-on:click="appTable.fetchData('')">заполнить таблицу</button>
  <app-table v-bind:filter-key="gridQuery" v-bind:headers="gridHeaders" v-bind:rows="gridRows">
  </app-table>
</div>
```

алгоритм работы прост: нажатие на кнопку заполняет таблицу из БД и сбрасывает массивы отвечающие за сортировку по столбцам, однако почему-то при изменении свойства **headers**, не пересчитывается **resSorting**.

Что я делаю не так, или я все делаю не так?

Если установить vue плагин для браузера, то после выделения в нем компонента все замечательно работает, однако если обновить таблицу и не выделить его сортировка не работает.

**обн:** исправил на верный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть мнение, что это связано с кэшированием вычисляемого свойства. Попробуйте вставить **resSorting** непосредственно в шаблон и оно пересчитается. В вашем случае можно использовать `watch` для слежения за `headers`.

Comment: действительно, перенес метод ** resSorting ** в директиву ** watch **, переименовав его в headers: { .. } и оно заработало.